# "on demand" LAMP stack

Tags: laptop, lamp

I'd like to install a LAMP stack on my laptop in order to be able to locally develop PHP websites. However, since my computer is a laptop, and since I don't always need having apache and MySQL server running, I'd like to setup a simple way to start and stop the LAMP stack when I need it. What method do you suggest to achieve that?

- Disable apache and mysql daemons and start / stop them when needed?
- Install LAMP stack on a virtual machine and share the network with the host to access the developed websites?
- Other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful tool (answering your first question) is [localhost-indicator](https://launchpad.net/localhost-indicator). With this application you have this functions **from a window with buttons**:

- open `http://localhost/` and phpMyAdmin in your Web browser,
- open your Public http documents directory,
- start/stop the Apache and MySQL services,
- edit the apache and php configuration.

[image: screenshoot]

---

Also, the must used commands in LAMP are the followings: *(always useful)*

**MySQL**

- Login:  `mysql -u <user> -p <db_to_use>`
- Start service: `sudo start mysql`
- Restart service: `sudo restart mysql`
- Stop service: `sudo stop mysql`

**Apache**

- Start service: `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl start`
- Restart service: `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl restart`
- Stop service: `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl stop`
- To test configuration changes: `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl configtest`